# Name of some category with two objects

Tags: category-theory

Does the category that consists of two objects and exactly one non-identity morphism that connects both objects have a specific name?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I think that we've already met on the MP. ;-)

Comment: Correct ;) Seems like here are more people answering on category theory questions (and my miserable language skills will benefit as well I hope ;))

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg what is MP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [interval](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+category) category. It is often denoted $\mathbf{I}$. Note that if $\mathbf{C}$ is category, then $\mathbf{C}^\mathbf{I}$ is the arrow category of $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Thanks! I have used it to show that the functor from Cat to Set that sends a small category to its arrow set is representable so your remark was helpful as well (in the sense that it confirmed my result).

Comment: The geometric realization of the interval category is the interval $[0,1]$. Therefore the name.

Answer (score 6):

As goblin suggests, "the interval category" is good, and it has the imprimatur of the nlab. I might also call it "the arrow category". If I say "the interval category", I somehow feel the need to clarify that I'm talking about the category with one nontrivial arrow, rather than one nontrivial isomorphism. I might also use the notation $\uparrow$, although this is hard to pronounce.

Another possibility is "the walking arrow" (as opposed to "the walking isomorphism"). In general, if you have a functor $F$ which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$, then you might call $X$ ["the walking $F$"](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/walking+structure) (in this case we have an isomorphism of 2-functors $\mathrm{Arr} \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\uparrow, - ): \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ where $\mathrm{Arr}$ sends a category $C$ to its [arrow category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category) $\mathrm{Arr} C$). This terminology probably feels a little too informal in some contexts, although it's fairly precise.

I suppose you could also say "the universal arrow" (as opposed to "the universal isomorphism").

Comment: Another good option would be: "let $\mathbf{I}$ denote the generic arrow." I agree that "interval category" can give the wrong impression.

Comment: I like this option with "the walking arrow" as it encodes further information on the usage of this category. Thanks for this.

Comment: I've been using $\textbf{I}_+$ for the directed interval category and $\textbf{I}$ for the interval groupoid. Kind of conflicts with notation for monos though. But it is a bit more extendable for stuff like delooping of the integers/naturals under addition $\textbf{S}$, $\textbf{S}_+$. "Circle groupoid" and "directed circle category" are kind of abusive terms anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

It might also be denoted $\mathbf 2$ as it is the category associated to the cardinal poset $\mathbf 2 = \{0<1\}$.

Comment: This notation is also used by Mac Lane and therefore by many other authors. It is easy to confuse with $2=\{0,1\}$, the discrete category on two objects, which is also the reason why I don't like this notation.

Comment: In this vein, I might also use $[1]$, viewing it as the 1-simplex.

Comment: My first idea was also to use 2 and my second thought was what Martin said. It's some kind of funny, I came with to less options and now I have to many.