# Category with two objects and two arrows.

Tags: category-theory

> Is the category where $\mathrm{Obj}$ has just two different elements $a$ and $b$ and the non identity arrows are $a \to b$ and $b \to a$ really a category? Does it have a name?

The thing is that the "usual" examples I've encountered so far have a lot of objects, like sets, groups, rings, topological spaces, etc... so I'm not sure if this construction leads to something that is not considered a category.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227044/name-of-some-category-with-two-objects) I can see that there is indeed a category with two objects and precisely one arrow, but I'd like to be sure that everything is okay if we add one more arrow on the other direction.

Comment: Well, technically you need to define what all the compositions are, but since there is only one choice, all that is left is to check that all the axioms of a category are satisfied (and indeed they are, as can also be seen by noting that this is the full subcategory of the category of sets given by picking two singleton sets).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It was confirmed in the comments that this is indeed a category. It also has a name: the [free(-standing) isomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/walking+isomorphism). Functors from this category into some category $\mathcal C$ are precisely isomorphisms in $\mathcal C$.